# Jenkins shows 404 page after login with Google

Tags: jenkins, google-signin

I followed instructions in Configure Global Security->Login with Google, and now I can log in with my Google account. The problem is, if I log out and try to log in again, the page shows 404 and says /securityRealm cannot be found. At this time I remove the /securityRealm in the URL and refresh my browser, I can successfully enter my Jenkins homepage and see my account already logged in. So how can I solve this issue?

Comment: what is your value for `Jenkis URL` configured in `Jenkins -> Configure System`?

Comment: @ChathuraBuddhika It's http://www.{my_company_domain}:8080

Comment: okay, add `http://` or `https://` in front of that and let me know the results regarding your issue. For example; `https://www.mycompanydomain.com:8080`. You may need to restart the Jenkins instance to take effect the changes.

Comment: @ChathuraBuddhika Yes, I've already added http:// in front of my Jenkins URL, and I also tried restarting jenkins several times. Everything stays unchanged.